# Any better way to manage activeComponent session data in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I would like to know if there is any better way to manage session's userdata for `activeComponent`. **activeComponent** is an ID of currently active component(plugin) I'am working on.

I have following components specified with an (id): Content(1), Users(2), AccessLvl(3), Ecommerce(4).

On *Categories Management* page, I'am checking for `$this->activeComponent`'s id, so I autoload category items which belongs to this component.

All controllers are extending `BaseController` and `class BaseController extends CI_Controller`. Inside that basecontroller I am doing that check for session data, which works fine, but I'am not sure if it's ok, or if there is any better way to do that ?

Here is my `app/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller{

    /**
     * Active component handler. 0 means nothing active
     */
    protected $activeComponent = 0;

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();


        // Check for session "activeComponent" data existance
        if( $this->session->userdata('activeComponent') !== FALSE ){
            // Assign a selected component from the session to the global var
            $this->activeComponent = $this->session->userdata('activeComponent');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_userdata('activeComponent', $this->activeComponent);
        }

    }



}
```